# How best to lay-out this inventory program

Tags: buttons, layout, winforms

I am a beginning programer and am working on creating a program that will allow people to keep track of inventory in their house. The program accepts barcodes scanned over a TCP/IP connection to add to the information.

**Currently, I have essentially all of the functions on the main form and am wondering if there is a better way to lay this out.**

[image: Main Form of Program]

I'll give a brief explanation of what the buttons do starting from top left.

> **File** - Opens menu with option to Exit 
> **Scan Barcode** - For testing purposes, open TCP/IP connection to scan barcode (Opens in new window)
> **Help** - Display menu with option to view IP address to ease the connection of TCP client(Opens in new window)
> **Search** - Searches items in the inventory (The big window)
> **Refresh** - Refreshes the list based on a database
> **Generate Barcode** - Converts user entered string into Barcode image to print onto labels.(Opens in new window)
> **Remove Selected** - Remove selected item from the inventory [database].
> **Add item** - Add item to inventory database (Opens in new window)

[image: Add Item Window]

Comment: Who are the users? What are they comfortable with?  How long are the field names?  Any competent designer can come up with dozens of designs based upon your wireframe.

Comment: @Mayo Users will be ranging from almost no experience with this type of software up to someone who is very competent and can figure things out on their own. Field names are quite short. I will add a screenshot of the 'Add Value' form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The right align of the search bar looked odd.
2. Buttons that operate on selected rows should be separated from other actions.
3. Checkboxes make it obvious that you can select the rows.
4. I increased the height of the search bar to emphasize it.
5. I would let the search button act as a refresh button if the search input isn't modified (of course it would need to change its icon accordingly).

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 0):

You could position the Buttons separately to indicate Primary Actions and other Actions could be positioned elsewhere.

If you want, you could try using something like a Material Design - Floating Action Button (However, you're developing for Windows, and this would mean not following the general design) since you seem to have 2 primary actions, namely:

**1. Add Item**

**2. Scan Barcode**

If you need inspiration, try using the Web Version of [Any.do](https://web.any.do/)

I feel the Strike animation to indicate a Done activity is amazing!